# how to use .load() to load only the specific div from a different html file

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I have an html file, and I am using `.load()` to load some part of **div** `photo_index` from another html file into a **div**  (`profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs`) in my original html. It does load the html file. But it loads the whole html file, and not only the div. What do I do to load only the needed div, ie.`photo_index`, from another html? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

html:

```
            <div id="profile_leftbar">

                <div id="profile_wrapper_container_summary">
                    <div id="profile_container_summary">
                        <div id="profile_summary">
                            <div id="profile_box1" class="box">
                                <a href="kkh.html" id="photo"><p>Photo</p>
                                    <p>450</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_box2" class="box">
                                <a href="#" id="video"><p>Video</p>
                                    <p>132</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_box3" class="box">
                                <a href="#" id="page"><p>Page</p>
                                    <p>14</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_box4" class="box">
                                <a href="#" id="forum"><p>Forum</p>
                                    <p>51</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_box5" class="box">
                                <a href="#" id="followers"><p>Followers</p>
                                    <p>551</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="profile_box6" class="box">
                                <a href="#" id="following"><p>Following</p>
                                    <p>317</p></a>
                            </div>
                            <span class="clear_left"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="profile_status">
                            <p>What???</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs">
                    <div id="profile_container_status_form">
                        <textarea class="profile_status_form"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div id="profile_container_logs">

                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 30th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Created a blog <a href="#">'This world'</a> on 17th oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 16th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Updated status 'Do you really think so?' on 10th Oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Uploaded video.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 30th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Created a blog <a href="#">'This world'</a> on 17th oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 16th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Updated status 'Do you really think so?' on 10th Oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Uploaded video.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 30th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Created a blog <a href="#">'This world'</a> on 17th oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Added photo on 16th oct</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Updated status 'Do you really think so?' on 10th Oct.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="profile_logs">
                            <p>Uploaded video.</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

another html:

```
    <div id="test">
        <h1>Testing the .load()</h1>
    </div>


    <div id="photo_index">



        <div id="tools_photo">
            <ul id="tools">
                <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Album</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tagged Photo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Upload Photo</a></li>
            <span class="clear_left"></span>
            </ul>
        </div>



        <div id="photo_index_page">

                <div id="container_thumbnail_container">
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img2.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img3.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img4.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img5.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img2.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img3.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img4.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail_container">
                        <a href="#" class="gallery" title="{{photo.title}}"><img src="img5.jpg" class="thumbnail" /></a>
                    </div>
                <span class="clear_left"></span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".box a").click(function () {
        $("#profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs").load(this.href + "#photo_index");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem:

Your current code will make a url like `http://dummy.com/index.html#photo_index` and this will load the whole html from the page.

```
$("#profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs").load(this.href + "#photo_index");
```

#### Solution:

Put a `" "` space before `" #photo_index"`:

```
$("#profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs").load(this.href + " #photo_index");
                                           //-------------^^--put a space here
```

or this way:

```
$("#profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs").load(this.href + " " +"#photo_index");
                                          //--------------^^--put a space here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var toLoad = this.href+' #photo_index';
$('#profile_wrapper_container_FormLogs').load(toLoad)
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your target division element in another html file have id #target (file name is another.html)
suppose your current division element in current html page have id #result

if you want to load that target element to your current result element then

use this code
$("#result").load("another.html **#target**", null, function(){
);

the first argument is the file url, second argument is the data to send to that url, third is the call back function. the #target specifies the target element in the another.html page.

thank u